# Entity framework exception: Failed to set Database.Default.ConnectionFactory to an instance of.. SQLConnectionFactory

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to change a running application from Pluralsight to write tables to SQL Server.

when i change the connection string from LocalDB to use SQL Server (see new app config sectionbelow), i get a System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of the 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SQLConnectionFactory, EntityFramework' type as specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework

The stack trace is below the app.config

**new app config (gets exception):**

```
app config sql server connection 
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
      type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SQLConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=GARY-PC\GARY;Initial Catalog=Dev;Integrated Security=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

**old app config**

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

**Stack trace:** 
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultConnectionFactory()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at ConsoleApp.Program.GetCustomers() in c:\Users\gary\Downloads\entity-framework5-getting-started\materials\4-ef5-m4-codefirst-exercise-files\SalesCodeFirst AFTER\ConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 22
       at ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\gary\Downloads\entity-framework5-getting-started\materials\4-ef5-m4-codefirst-exercise-files\SalesCodeFirst AFTER\ConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 15
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
       HResult=-2146233054
       Message=Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SQLConnectionFactory' from assembly 'EntityFramework'.
       Source=mscorlib
       TypeName=System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SQLConnectionFactory
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
            at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.DefaultConnectionFactoryElement.GetFactoryType()
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.<.ctor>b__1()
       InnerException:

Comment: The detailed error message is: {"Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SQLConnectionFactory' from assembly 'EntityFramework'.":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SQLConnectionFactory"}
                                                                                                                   ***I can see System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory in the objectbrowser, so why will it not load?***

Comment: I meant ***In the project i am running , i can browse in the object browser from entity frameowrk to  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory , so why will it not load?***